# Non index root path with Marionette router

Tags: backbone.js, url-routing, marionette

I have to serve up my backbone app on the "/b"  route and am having trouble hooking in my router.  It works fine if I just showView a view, but my route controller functions are not firing when I hook in my router, any thoughts?

router:

```
define('appRouter', ['marionette', 'rootView', 'changePasswordView'], function(Marionette, rootView, changePasswordView) {
  return Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    routes: {
      '/b/change-password': 'showChangePassword',
      '/b': 'showAccountSettings'
    },
    showChangePassword: function() {
      this.showView(new changePasswordView());
    },
    showAccountSettings: function() {
      this.showView(new rootView());
    }
  });
});
```

application onStart (which is confirmed firing):

```
 var Application = Marionette.Application.extend({

...

    onStart: function(options) {
      console.log('on start');
      var router = new appRouter(options);
      /** Starts the URL handling framework */
      if( ! Backbone.History.started) Backbone.history.start();
      router.initialize();
    }, 

...

});
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8080/b` (which is for all intensive purposes my index) it renders a blank page.

Comment: where are you registering the route in your Marionette.Application?Can you post code for that?

Comment: That may be were I'm missing it, the onStart shown is in the  ```Application = Marionette.Application.extend({ ... })``` class extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default routes in Backbone are [hash-based](http://backbonejs.org/#Router). Link to Your `/b` route should look like `http://localhost:8080/#/b`.

If You don't need **hash-based** links, start history with `pushState: true`.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

**EDIT:**

If You serve app on `/b` path, then You have wrong defined routes. Routes must be defined relative to `/b`:

```
routes: {
  'change-password': 'showChangePassword',
  '': 'showAccountSettings'
},
```

And access:

- `http://localhost:8080/b' -`showAccountSettings`
- `http://localhost:8080/b#change-password' -`showChangePassword`

Comment: The app is served off the '/b' path, not the '/' path.  It won't (and shouldn't) have access to anything before '/b'